# Writing more if else statements than necessary (C#)

Tags: c#, if-statement, while-loop

I am a few days new to the C# language and wanted to challenge myself by writing a program to convert a normal integer to hexadecimal. I think this program works properly but I want to get rid of the second set of if/else statements, is it possible to rewrite the code in the while loop for that to happen?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace IntegerToHexadecimal
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Please Enter an integer");
            int input = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            string output = "";

            int answer = input / 16;
            int remainder = input % 16;

            while (answer != 0)
            {

                if (remainder < 10) output = Convert.ToString(remainder) + output;
                else if (remainder == 10) output = "A" + output;
                else if (remainder == 11) output = "B" + output;
                else if (remainder == 12) output = "C" + output;
                else if (remainder == 13) output = "D" + output;
                else if (remainder == 14) output = "E" + output;
                else if (remainder == 15) output = "F" + output;

                input = answer;
                answer = input / 16;
                remainder = input % 16;

            }

            if (remainder < 10) output = Convert.ToString(remainder) + output;
            else if (remainder == 10) output = "A" + output;
            else if (remainder == 11) output = "B" + output;
            else if (remainder == 12) output = "C" + output;
            else if (remainder == 13) output = "D" + output;
            else if (remainder == 14) output = "E" + output;
            else if (remainder == 15) output = "F" + output;


            Console.WriteLine("Your number in hexadecimal is: 0x" + output);
            Console.ReadLine();

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: why not `ToString("X")` this will do show you the hex of int

Comment: @MohitShrivastava there is  no 'G' in hex.

Comment: @pwas you are absolutely correct. I have not seen it though but now the question arise is that the OP is writing it HEX everywhere. `Console.WriteLine("Your number in hexadecimal is: 0x" + output);` and `namespace IntegerToHexadecimal` and in the description as well

Comment: @MohitShrivastava ahh right, so it seems that the OP's code is not working correctly.

Comment: My bad @pwas new guy here didn't realize there's no G in hex

Comment: @Joormatt see my answer - I have explained why your code is working after all and how to get rid of 'G' :)

Comment: no problem @Joormatt bcoz reminder cannot be 16 at any point of time. So those lines are null and void automatically

Comment: I know you are trying to implement logic for conversion but, if you just want to write hex of int then only this line will also suffice: `Console.WriteLine("Your number in hexadecimal is: 0x{0:x}", input);`

Comment: @Joormatt did u tried the solution I have suggested. Does it helped you?

Answer (score 0):

Little hack:

```
if (remainder < 10) output = Convert.ToString(remainder) + output;
else if (remainder <= 16) 
{
    int result = 'A' + (remainder - 10);
    output = (char)result + output;
}
```

Anyway - if you want to convert dec into hex your code is wrong. There is no `G` in hex.
So case with `remainder == 16` will never happen - the output of `remainder % 16` belongs to set `[0...15]`.

So you can put: `else if (remainder <= 15)` as well.

Comment: @Joormatt I have improved casting - the answer before could not compile, now it works for sure - tested.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the last if else condition is repetitive and you want to get rid of it. So the situation is `answer` becomes zero and we still wanted to run the loop once again. There could be many option to handle this but I would like to tell you three of them

1. You can make a function for the if else so that u just call the function and your code would look simple clean and neat. But yes it is not a solution. This only increase the redability.
2. You can go for a do while loop instead of while, because do while check the condition later but first run the loop.
3. You can write a boolean variable to check if the loop should run or not and in the loop we can have a condition which checks whethere the loop has been executed once or not. Below is the code for reference.

This might solves your if else condition repeating code after the loop. Give it a try.

```
int answer = input / 16;
int remainder = input % 16;
bool shudloop = true;
int cntshudloop = 0;
while(shudloop)
{

    if(remainder < 10)
        output = Convert.ToString(remainder) + output;
    else if(remainder == 10)
        output = "A" + output;
    else if(remainder == 11)
        output = "B" + output;
    else if(remainder == 12)
        output = "C" + output;
    else if(remainder == 13)
        output = "D" + output;
    else if(remainder == 14)
        output = "E" + output;
    else if(remainder == 15)
        output = "F" + output;

    input = answer;
    answer = input / 16;
    remainder = input % 16;
    if(answer == 0)
    {
        if(cntshudloop >= 1)
            shudloop = false;

        cntshudloop++;
    }

}
```